# GNU make substitution command for automatic list of object files

Tags: makefile

A common type of makefile has a line like this:

```
OBJS=something.o other.o third.o progname.o

progname: $(OBJS)
```

Then you would run `make progname`.  But GNU Make can also generate the list of o-files itself from all the c-files it sees in the current directory. How is this done?

Basically, I want to be able to add C files to the directory without having to change the makefile.

<sup>(Is it for instance through some shell-magic, or is there is a built-in function for this?)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To view all the defined rules (include the implicit ones), issue `make -p`.

However the fact that make knows how to generate object files from source files, does not mean that it *should* do this. Make will try to do the bare minimum in order to satisfy the target you ask it to build.

If you want make to compile all the sources into object in the current directory you will need a rule that will depend on all the objects, e.g.:

```
all: $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))
```

Comment: I took the liberty to change from 'shell ls *.c' to 'wildcard *.c' since that is more portable.

Comment: Thank, @Amigable Clark Kant, indeed the `$(shell ls)` is the ugly way to do it, and your solution is certainly cleaner.

Answer (score 5):

It can also be done like this:

```
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

progname: $(OBJS)
```

Which works just fine if the object file with `main()` in it is "progname.o".

Answer (score 1):

You can expand a shell command to give you a list of files. You can also use [implicit rules](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/make_10.html).

Comment: You'll have to look at the docs on that page. The basic idea is that `make` "knows" how to create certain binaries from sources for a large number of "standard" programs. You can use this knowledge to simply tell it "this is the target - build it from appropriately named sources". I can't give you examples since it's been over 3 years since I've used make and it's swapped out of my head.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this:

```
$(ODIR)/%.o: %.cpp
   $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

make generates .o file names from .cpp file names it found in the current directory.

Comment: @Amigable Clark Kant: nope, you define it yourself

Comment: It seems to work perfectly fine without that rule, so I guess there is an implicit rule already.